# My background does not appear

Tags: css, background-image

For some reason the background does not appear.

This is the CSS

```
div.sidebar_beige {
background: no-repeat left top;
height: 142px;
margin: 35px 0 35px 0;
position: relative;}

div.sidebar_beige h3 {
    color: #f57f20;
    font-family: 'trebuchet ms';
    font-size: 17px;
    left: 15px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    width: 163px;
}
div.sidebar_beige p {
color: #454343;
font-family: 'trebuchet ms';
font-size: 12px;
left: 15px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
position: absolute;
top: 42px;
width: 165px;}

div.sidebar_fcs {
 background-image: url('../images/sidebar_backup_online.png');
}
div.sidebar_lap {
 background-image: url('../images/sidebar_backup_laptoprepara.png');
}
```

This is the html used:

```
<div class="sidebar_lap sidebar_beige">
            <h3>
              Laptop Reparatie
            </h3>
            <p>

              U kan niet gelijk een nieuwe<br />
            laptop kopen? <br />
            We zijn de goedkoopste<br />
            van Friesland.
            </p>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the order of overrides to your advantage here:

Make the copied.css just include:

```
div.sidebar_beige_lap {
  background: url('../images/sidebar_backup_laptoprepara.png') no-repeat left top;
}
```

In your page, include them in order:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="original.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="copied.css" />
```

Any properties overridden in `copied.css` will win, otherwise properties from `original.css` are inherited.

Comment: When I have a lot of different pages I will have about 12 different style sheets in my css folder ;)

Comment: @chris, you can do the same with a style tag, or an overlapping styles, the multiple sheets example was just to match your original scenario.

Comment: I understand what you mean, I'll give it a try thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1):

If possible, the best way is to give each page a unique or helpful class and/or ID on the body element. So, just for an example, one page is:

```
<body class="bg-custom">
```

and another is

```
<body class="bg-custom-right">
```

Then in your CSS you can alter it like so:

```
.bg-custom #selector { background-img: url(...);}
.bg-custom-right #selector { background-img: url(...);}
```

where `#selector` is the element that you want to change on each page--but without having to give each one it's own new (copied) style rules or class name(s), making your CSS and HTML cleaner and easier to maintain. (As a bonus, if there's anything else you need to use the same trick on for per-page editing, you can do so.)

Answer (score 0):

use two classes on your div:

```
<div class="sidebar lap">...
```

Pull the bg mage out of the sidebar class so that all divs can share it. The set up a new class for each different bg you need (lpa, fcs, etc) which contains *only* the bg image.

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple CSS classes assignment:

HTML FCS:

```
<div class="sidebar_fcs sidebar_beige">...</div>
```

HTML LAP:

```
<div class="sidebar_lap sidebar_beige">...</div>
```

Single CSS:

```
div.sidebar_beige {
 background: no-repeat left top;
 height: 142px;
 margin: 35px 0 35px 0;
 position: relative;
}
div.sidebar_beige h3 {
 color: #f57f20;
 font-family: 'trebuchet ms';
 font-size: 17px;
 left: 15px;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 15px;
 width: 163px;
}
div.sidebar_beige p {
 color: #454343;
 font-family: 'trebuchet ms';
 font-size: 12px;
 left: 15px;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 42px;
 width: 165px;
}
div.sidebar_fcs {
 background-image: url('../images/sidebar_backup_online.png');
}
div.sidebar_lap {
 background-image: url('../images/sidebar_backup_laptoprepara.png');
}
```

Comment: I tried your sollution but the background doesn't apear anywhere, I updated my qestion with your sollution.

Comment: @Chris, oops, the class for the div 'sidebar_beige_lap' should be 'sidebar_lap'. I've corrected the typo in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your background image is on the `sidebar_lap` class.

In your HTML you use `sidebar_beige_lap`

Change your HTML to

```
<div class="sidebar_lap sidebar_beige">
```